# Oracle 10g express database link to Oracle 8i

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-10g

I upgraded a 9i install to 11g with only one problem.  Database links between 11g and our legacy 8i database are no longer supported.  I have to transfer data from 11g to 8i two or three times a day so I thought it might be possible to use 10g express to link the databases.
The data would be created in 11g, written to a table in 10g and then written to 8i.  (I agree this is not the most elegant solution and I can improve it using advanced queue tables).

Does 10g express support database links to Oracle 8i?

Edit: thanks for the link to the Oracle documentation.  Has anyone actually done this with 10g express?

Edit:  The 8i database is Oracle8i Enterprise Edition Release 8.1.7.0.0 - Production
The intermediate would be the 10g express for windows
The origin database is Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production

Comment: Exactly what version of 8i are you using?

Comment: I can now verify that Oracle 10 XE can connect to Oracle 8i with a database link.  Those of you with legacy databases can still keep in touch from 11g at no cost

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Metalink 207303.1 is the [Client/ Server Interoperability Matrix](https://support.oracle.com/CSP/main/article?cmd=show&type=NOT&id=207303.1) which will be the definitive documentation.  Since the express edition of 10g is based on Oracle 10.2, a database link to an 8.1.7 database should be supported.  Database links to earlier versions of 8i (8.1.5 or 8.1.6) are not supported from a 10.2 database.  For general sanity, I'd strongly suggest that the 8i side be running at least the 8.1.7.4 patchset but that isn't strictly required.